# How to change date format in nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Hello I'm displaying date from db at frontend using nodejs, ejs but its showing like this:

[image]

But I wants that it only shows `02.02.2020`

**ejs code:**

```
<p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"><%= meeting.date %></p>
```

**controller code:**

```js
var renderListOfMeetings = async function(req, res) {
    try {
        checkRoles(req);
        const meetings = await Meeting.find({});
        res.render('meeting', {
            title: 'Meetings',
            pdfUrl: config.pdfUrl,
            isAdmin: req.roleAdmin,
            sectionBCommittee: [],
            meetings: meetings
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex.message);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‍ You can create this function on your controller code:

```js
function convertDate(d) {
  const date = new Date(d);
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  let month = date.getMonth();
  month = parseInt(month) < 10 ? `0${month}` : month;

  let day = date.getDate();
  day = parseInt(day) < 10 ? `0${day}` : day;
  return day + "." + month + "." + year;
}
```

> **You can change the function name** like as what you want.

After that, you can passing the function in your `renderMeetingLists`, so it's will looks like this code below:

```js
var renderListOfMeetings = async function (req, res) {
  try {
    checkRoles(req);
    const meetings = await Meeting.find({});
    res.render('meeting', {
        title: 'Meetings',
        pdfUrl : config.pdfUrl,
        isAdmin : req.roleAdmin,
        sectionBCommittee: [],
        meetings: meetings,
        // your convert date function
        convertDate: convertDate
    });
  }catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
  }
};
```

**Updated:** So your **final `js` code** will looks like this code below

```js
function convertDate(d) {
  const date = new Date(d);
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  let month = date.getMonth();
  month = parseInt(month) < 10 ? `0${month}` : month;

  let day = date.getDate();
  day = parseInt(day) < 10 ? `0${day}` : day;
  return day + "." + month + "." + year;
}

var renderListOfMeetings = async function (req, res) {
  try {
    checkRoles(req);
    const meetings = await Meeting.find({});
    res.render('meeting', {
        title: 'Meetings',
        pdfUrl : config.pdfUrl,
        isAdmin : req.roleAdmin,
        sectionBCommittee: [],
        meetings: meetings,
        // your convert date function
        convertDate: convertDate
    });
  }catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
  }
};
```

After you passing your `convertDate`, now you can use it in your `ejs`. It's will looks like this code below:

```
<p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"><%= convertDate(meeting.date) %></p>
```

I hope it can help you .

Comment: function convertDate(d) {
              ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function       paste.ofcode.org/MfKWxVgnrwczPxLmCXapSJ

Comment: That's why it's error, beacuse you put your function in there. In my example code ebove, it's not looks like it. I've been update the final result then you can check it out.

Comment: \meeting.ejs:225 223| <p style="padding-top: 15px; font-size: 25px; 224| font-weight: bold;"><%= meeting.subject %></p> >> 225| <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"><%= convertDate(meeting.date) %></p> 226| <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">Upcoming</p> 227| </span> 228| </div> convertDate is not defined

Comment: Please read my comment, make sure it's same. There's no error if it's same. The function name you pass in your `js` then you use it in your `ejs`.

Comment: its same but actually ist color in function is dim u can see https://ibb.co/w76Dv3p                            https://ibb.co/vzHV5SH

Comment: In your code in that image, you have no pass your convertDate function. Please copy my final result and replace your function in that image.